# Razor: Why isn't this button passing an argument to the OnGet method of the directed page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have the following button in a .schtml file:

```
<form method="get">
    <button asp-page="/SavedQueries" type="submit" asp-route-input="@Model._input">Save Query</button>
</form>
```

Which calls the `OnGet()` method of the SavedQueries.cshtml.cs page:

```
public void OnGet(MatchingInput<PinInformation<int>> input)
        {
            DoStuff()
        }
```

But the object I passed into the asp-route-input field is not passed across and then the OnGet method is called with a new instantiation of the class

Comment: Is there a [HttpPost] attribute on the method?

Comment: this is a razor page so I don't believe Http attributes are required. But I'm not sure. When I one I get the following warning: 'HttpGetAttribute' cannot be applied to Razor Page handler methods. Routes for Razor Pages must be declared using the @page directive or using conventions.

Comment: Is this Blazor? Does the page end with .cshtml or .razor?

Comment: the page ends with cshtml

Comment: the SaveQuery page is .cshtlm.cs

Comment: You can pass simple data withasp-route-xxx,can you share the structure of `@Model._input`or `MatchingInput<PinInformation<int>>`?